# Cannot Convert between Expression<Func<...>> and Func<...>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, lambda

A method I am trying to call (third party, can't change) expects a `Func<TResult>`. Using reflection I am trying to make an e.g. `Func<Task<IEnumerable<Person>>>` but I am inadvertently creating an `Expression<Func<Task<IEnumerable<Person>>>>`. The reason for reflection is that person is arbitrary and could be any type depending on how/when this is called.

```
// trying to mimic this hard-code: () => TaskEx.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<Person>())
//var enumerableType = typeof(Person); //potentially

var empty = (typeof(Enumerable)).GetMethod("Empty");
var genereicEmpty = empty.MakeGenericMethod(enumerableType);
var emptyEnumerable = genereicEmpty.Invoke(null, null);

var fromResult = typeof (TaskEx).GetMethod("FromResult");
var genericFromResult = fromResult.MakeGenericMethod(genereicEmpty.ReturnType);

var enumerableTask = genericFromResult.Invoke(null, new [] {emptyEnumerable});

var functype = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(genericFromResult.ReturnType);
var body = Expression.Constant(enumerableTask);
var lambdaType = typeof(Expression).GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Lambda")
    .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Where(x => x.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(ParameterExpression[]))
    .Single(x => x.IsGenericMethod);
var genericLambdaType = lambdaType.MakeGenericMethod(functype);
var lambda = genericLambdaType.Invoke(null, new object[] { body, new ParameterExpression[0] });
```

When I use lambda later I get the exception

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DC.Dataloader.Models.Person]]]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DC.Dataloader.Models.Person]]]'.
```

Is there a better way than `Expression.Lambda` to build a `Func<>` on the fly? I can't seem to find the correct way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `.Compile()` method, which does exactly that.

Side note:
You don't need to call the `Expression` APIs using Reflection; you can use the non-generic `Expression.Lambda()`, which will still return a `Func<T>`:

```
Expression.Lambda(body).Compile()
```

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe it was right under my nose. Glad to get rid of that `typeof(Func<>)` and `lambdaType/genericLambdaType` query too. Thanks